# Shell Exec Write Error

Tags: php

I am running in to some problems with shell exec and tail I am trying to run the following

```
$x = 2;
$y = 5;

$command = "tail -n +$x $file | head -n $((Y-X+$y))";

$output = shell_exec($command);
```

I am then getting the following

```
tail: write error
```

followed by my requested information.

The tail command runs fine in shell but fails when running in php.

I have tried proc_open() and popen() with the same results. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: does php have read write access to the file?

Comment: @Dagon It sure does, has no problem reading the file but still getting that error

Comment: tested locally works, has to be a permission error, remember php and you will have different privileges.

Comment: It may run good in shell because you run it as other user. PHP could be executed as `www-data`. Try run it as `sudo -u www-data bash -c 'tail ...'` and see if you get the same errors as in PHP